# Reading a large CSV file and processing in C#. Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, csv, data-structures, large-files

I have a large CSV file around 25G. I need to parse each line which has around 10 columns and do some processing and finally save it to a new file with parsed data.

I am using dictionary as my datastructure. To avoid the memory overflow I am writing the file after 500,000 records and clearing the dictionary.

Can anyone suggest whether is this good way of doing. If not, any other better way of doing this? **Right now it is taking 30 mins to process 25G file**.

Here is the code

```
        private static void ReadData(string filename, FEnum fileType)
    {

       var resultData = new ResultsData
                        {
                            DataColumns = new List<string>(),
                            DataRows = new List<Dictionary<string, Results>>()
                        };

                    resultData.DataColumns.Add("count");
                    resultData.DataColumns.Add("userid");

                    Console.WriteLine("Start Processing : " + DateTime.Now);
                    const long processLimit = 100000;
                        //ProcessLimit : 500000, TimeElapsed : 30 Mins;
                        //ProcessLimit : 100000, TimeElaspsed - Overflow

                    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

                    stopwatch.Start();
                    Dictionary<string, Results> parsedData = new Dictionary<string, Results>();

                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        string charsRead = streamReader.ReadLine();

                        int count = 0;
                        long linesProcessed = 0;

                        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(charsRead))
                        {

                            string[] columns = charsRead.Split(',');
                            string eventsList = columns[0] + ";" + columns[1] + ";" + columns[2] + ";" + columns[3] + ";" +
                                                columns[4] + ";" + columns[5] + ";" + columns[6] + ";" + columns[7];
                            if (parsedData.ContainsKey(columns[0]))
                            {
                                Results results = parsedData[columns[0]];
                                results.Count = results.Count + 1;
                                results.Conversion = results.Count;

                                results.EventList.Add(eventsList);
                                parsedData[columns[0]] = results;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Results results = new Results {
                                                    Count = 1, Hash_Person_Id = columns[0], Tag_Id = columns[1], Conversion = 1,
                                                    Campaign_Id = columns[2], Inventory_Placement = columns[3], Action_Id = columns[4], 
                                                    Creative_Group_Id = columns[5], Creative_Id = columns[6], Record_Time = columns[7]
                                                    };
                                results.EventList = new List<string> {eventsList};

                                    parsedData.Add(columns[0], results);
                            }
                            charsRead = streamReader.ReadLine();

                            linesProcessed++;

                            if (linesProcessed == processLimit)
                            {
                                linesProcessed = 0;
                                SaveParsedValues(filename, fileType, parsedData);
//Clear Dictionary
                                parsedData.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(@"File  : {0}  Batch Limit : {1}  Time elapsed : {2} ", filename + Environment.NewLine, processLimit + Environment.NewLine, stopwatch.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine);

                }
```

**Thank you**

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would probably get a gain in performance by having one thread reading in lines and adding them to a queue and another thread processing the lines from the queue, a typical producer/consumer scenario.

Comment: a threaded approach is certainly smart, however a single 25G process is still a 25G process and will take time.  in order to avoid potential recurring annoyances like parse errors or external issues you could always split the data into multiple temporary files.  count every 50k lines, pass into new temp XML files.  then run through the temps (or write->process->write->etc) and store a progress object so you can resume if needed.

Comment: I would suggest looking into parallelism and multithreading if you can.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx#Y0) class looks like it could do the job.  Try it, it may speed things up.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the TextFieldParser. If not dictionary, which data structure do you suggest?

Comment: Ah, I didn't fully understand the dictionary usage in your code at first glance.

Comment: Dan-o, TextFieldParser which replaces the split in my code did not help much.